# parse KML file with geoxml3 and markerclusterer

Tags: maps, geoxml3

I'm using geoxml3 and markerclusterer to parse a kml file to a google maps api v3 map. this works so far.

the kml file stores several information.

```
<Placemark>
   <name>Manfred Mustermann</name>
   <description>Manfred Mustermann</description>
   <Point>
      <coordinates>7.0964850607874,51.781641735074,0</coordinates>
   </Point>
   <address>Musterstr. 29 Aachen, 52070 Nordrhein-Westfalen</address>
   <styleUrl>#0</styleUrl>
</Placemark>
```

It´s working to output the Nodes "name" or "description" but not the "address". If I try to output this with place mark.address, undefined is written in the info window.

My Question is, how can I parse also this address info?

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myOptions = {
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 80, maxZoom: 15};
    markers = [];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    markerclusterer  = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth:800});

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map, 
    singleInfoWindow:true,

    createMarker:function(placemark){
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(placemark.point.lat, placemark.point.lng);
            var con = "<pre>" + placemark.description + "<br /><br />" + placemark.address + "</pre>";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:point});
            markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
                infoWindow.content = con;
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
           markerclusterer.addMarker(marker);
    }
});
    myParser.parse('dat.kml');
  });

  function clickMarker(i){
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Toni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the 'geoxml3.js' file. In the 'var render = function (responseXML, doc)', placemark is defined as:

```
placemark = {
      name:  geoXML3.nodeValue(node.getElementsByTagName('name')[0]),
      description: geoXML3.nodeValue(node.getElementsByTagName('description')[0]),
styleUrl: geoXML3.nodeValue(node.getElementsByTagName('styleUrl')[0])
};
```

Change it to add:

```
address: geoXML3.nodeValue(node.getElementsByTagName('address')[0])
```

Keep in mind that adding an address tag to KML is not in the standards of KML. Better to use a tag such as ExtendedData https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata#entityreplacement .